# Conflict between Eigen and operator that uses ‘auto’ in another (template) class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, operator-overloading, eigen

I have a template class called "Variable.h", which serves as the basis for all program variables.
After Eigen was added to handle matrix calculations, every time I compile the program, I get a series of errors, which look like conflicts between operator overload, auto operator and Eigen.
I only get the erros in Linux, in Windows it compiles normally (i just started using Linux).
I'm using C++17 and g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0 version

Here are the errors and one of the lines that it accuses as an error

```
Variable.h: In instantiation of ‘auto operator<=(T, U) [with T = Eigen::internal::unpacket_traits<__vector(2) double>::<unnamed enum>; U = int]’:
Variable.h:290:80:   required from ‘auto operator>=(T, U) [with T = int; U = Eigen::internal::unpacket_traits<__vector(2) double>::<unnamed enum>]’
Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:30:115:   required from ‘struct Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> >’
Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:98:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> >’
Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:178:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>’
SoilOrganicMatter.h:499:19:   required from here
Variable.h:291:80: error: use of ‘auto operator>=(T, U) [with T = int; U = Eigen::internal::unpacket_traits<__vector(2) double>::<unnamed enum>]’ before deduction of ‘auto’
  291 |  T, typename U> auto operator <= (T lhs, U rhs) { return rhs >= lhs; };
      |
```

Variable.h, lines 290 and 291

```
template <typename T, typename U> auto operator >= (T lhs, U rhs) { return rhs <= lhs; };
template <typename T, typename U> auto operator <= (T lhs, U rhs) { return rhs >= lhs; };
```

SoilOrganicMatter.h line 499

```
Eigen::Matrix3d carbonPart;
```

If i comment the overloading operators, i get rid of the errors, and it seems to be ok, but i did not wrote this class, so i don't know all of it's impact through the program.

Could someone help me figure out what's wrong, or find any clues please?

Comment: You try to define each of `<=` and `>=` in terms of the other…?

Comment: "_i did not wrote this class_": Find whoever wrote it and ask them what the heck that's intended to do because these overloads don't seem to make any sense at all.